# PostgreSQL: Excluding Connected IDs based on null or not null value

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I am working with a database that looks at user accounts and tracks behaviors. Sometimes user accounts are connected (e.g. the users are married).

For a particular analysis I am doing, I want to avoid double counting connected users as it will inflate my number of conversions. Below is a sample data set.

How would I count the number of ids with a non-null date without double counting connected users? As you can see, sometimes the connected_id is a chain of 3 ids.

```
|   ID   |   Connected_ID    |  DATE_A      |
|   1    |      10           | 2018-09-15   |
|   2    |                   | 2018-10-02   |
|   3    |      5            | 2018-06-01   |
|   4    |                   | 2018-06-01   |
|   5    |      7            |              |
|   6    |                   | 2018-07-10   |
|   7    |      5            | 2018-06-01   |
|   8    |                   |              |
|   9    |                   | 2018-05-05   |
|   10   |      1            | 2018-09-15   |
```

From this sample, I would want to get the following result:

```
|  DATE_A   |   COUNT_IDS  |
| 2018-05-05|     1        |
| 2018-06-01|     2        |
| 2018-07-10|     1        |
| 2018-09-15|     1        |
| 2018-10-02|     1        |
```

Normally I would accomplish this with a SQL query like below:

```
Select DATE_A, count(*) FROM table_1 GROUP BY 1
```

This would obviously not account for the connected accounts and would inflate my count.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So user 5 is married to both 3 and 7?

Comment: I hope polygamy isn't a thing but I suspect one might be a child or perhaps grandparent who lives with the married pair.

Comment: If  `2018-10-02` have 1 as count, then why `2018-06-01` have 2 instead of 3 ?

Comment: 2018-06-01 has user 4 and user 3 and user 7. But user 3 and user 7 are connected (via user 5), so I wouldn't want to count both 3 and 7 as that would be double counting that connected group. So I would count 1 for user 4 and 1 for user 3/5/7.

Comment: Are marriages in your world limited to bigamy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt where I used UNION to join two queries

```
SELECT Date_A, COUNT(id_count) 
FROM (SELECT Date_A, 1 as id_count
      FROM test
      WHERE DATE_A IS NOT NULL AND connected_id IS NULL
      UNION 
      SELECT Date_A, 2 as id_count
      FROM test
      WHERE DATE_A IS NOT NULL AND connected_id IS NOT NULL) as uni
GROUP BY Date_A
```

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thanks! Definitely not a solution that I would have come up with myself. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COUNT(col)` instead of `COUNT(*)`:

```
Select DATE_A, count(Connected_id) FROM table_1 GROUP BY DATE_A;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this wouldn't count the ids that do not have connected ids though. I want to connect all ids with a date but just don't want to double count those that are connected.

Comment: Based on my test, this is not giving me a count for 2018-10-02 because there is no connected_id. I would want to count that user though.